# What does "here's to someone/thing" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context

I got an email from an instructor today. Towards the end of email she says:

> "Here is to finishing off the semester in a positive way."

What does that mean?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"Here's to ..." is a phrase used when making a toast. It means "Here is a toast to ...", at which point it is customary to raise your glass. The phrase has a life of its own, used by a speaker or writer expresses a situation that calls for a toast-like salute to something.

The "Here is" part can be omitted also. For instance, the wording of a toast may simply be something like, "To your health!"

The preposition or particle "to ~" in this situation means something like: "for the sake of the (continued) good status of ~" or "in recognition/appreciation/celebration/congratulation of ~" or "in hope of ~"

> "Here is to you, Bob!" -> "Here is a toast in appreciation of you, Bob!"
>
> "To your health!" -> "Let this symbolic drink be made for the sake of the continued good status of your health!"
>
> "Here is to finishing off the semester in a positive way."
>
> -> "Here is a wish in hope of finishing off the rest of the semester in a positive way."
>
> -> "Here is a cheer in celebration of having finished the semester in a positive way."

Comment: Ooh, downvote with no comment. Here is to the plus-voters out there! All you others: do not hate, emulate. :)

Comment: There you go - have my upvote to counterbalance the dark force. Not that the other answers are *wrong* - but they give no explanation as to how the expression arose in the first place, so they're incomplete.

Comment: It may also be related to the the expression hear, hear. As is discussed in this wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_here

Answer (score 6):

It is a way of expressing a wish for success. In other words: "I hope you will finish off the semester in a positive way".

Answer (score 1):

"Here is to..." or "Here's to..." is a friendly way of saying "I am looking forward to..."

Another example: A salesman may say at the end of the year: "Here's to another great year of sales"